# How to make a path available for the entire system in Ubuntu

Tags: ubuntu, c++, header-file

My tflite directory is as follows:

```
/home/me/tensorflow_src/tensorflow/lite/
```

However, I fail to import it in my C++ project:

```
#include "tensorflow/lite/interpreter.h" // getting a not found error
```

How can I add resolve this error? My assumption is that I'd need to add the tflite to my bash to make it available for all of my projects. How can I add tflite to the bash file?

This is my CMAKE file:

```
cmake_minimum_required(VERSION 3.22)
project(mediafile_device_crossverification)

set(CMAKE_CXX_STANDARD 17)

set(OpenCV FOUND 1)
find_package(OpenCV REQUIRED)
include_directories( ${OpenCV_INCLUDE_DIRS} )
add_executable(mediafile_device_crossverification main.cpp src/VideoProcessing.cpp src/VideoProcessing.h)
```

Answer (score 2):

The C++ compiler must be told where to find header files that you include. Depending on what compiler you use, this may be done with the `-I` option on the command line:

```bash
c++ -I ~/tensorflow_src ...other options etc...
```

If you have some sort of integrated development environment (IDE) that invokes the compiler for you, it may allow you to configure from where header files will be read.

Some software may use a Makefile that may call the compiler with a set of fairly common environment variables.  One of these variables is called `CXXFLAGS`, which contains flags used by the C++ container (it may also use `CPPFLAGS` which is usually used for the C and C++ compilers' pre-processor).  You may possibly use this to define the location of your header files when invoking `make`:

```bash
CPPFLAGS="-I/home/me/tesorflow_src" make
```

The best option would be to refer to the documentation of the software that you are trying to build (if it's not your private project that is), or possibly to the development documentation for the tensorflow project, which should tell you how to make best use of it.

Comment: Moreover, when using include paths like specified above, you will have to use them like `-I <header.h>`. The form `-I "header.h"` applies a local source relative path.

Comment: @gerhardd. You meant `#include` rather than `-I`, right?

Comment: @gerhardd. Also, if I'm not mistaken, `-I` affects the path used by both types of `#include` statements.

Comment: @kusalandnda Yes, you're right. i meant `#include`. :-)

Comment: Check the edits. I've pasted my cmake file..